# NUnit - Assert that method call is within MaxTime without setup time

Tags: c#, nunit

I have some acceptance test that assert that some method calls take less time then a maximum value. With my current solution NUnit adds the time of the setup to the method call.

How can I test the time of the method call without the setup time?

**Current code:**

```
private ISession session;

[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    //NHibernate session factory created and a session created
    //Takes about 1 second which is added to the method call timeout
}

[Test, MaxTime(3000)]
public void ShouldTakeLessThanThreeSeconds()
{
    //Execute test
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [FluentAssertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions) (a must-have tool IMO).

It provides an [`ExecutionTimeOf`](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#execution-time) extension which can be chained with `ShouldNotExceed`.

```
sut.ExecutionTimeOf(x => x.Method())
   .ShouldNotExceed(3.Seconds());
```